# Using chrome bookmarks getTree function with callback for data source with jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, jstree

I'm creating a chrome extension that populates a [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) with the user's Chrome bookmarks. I am obtaining and modifying the json data returned via chrome.bookmarks.getTree with the following code. I need to figure out how to obtain and modify the data all by passing a function into the tree initiation. JsTree docs say you can pass a function in as data [here](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/). I'm thinking it may not be possible though because of the callback... I'm not sure. Does anyone know how to do this?

My current code... need to change it to include getting and modifying all the data in the tree initialization:

```
function initBookmarks(){
  chrome.bookmarks.getTree(parseBookmarks);
}

function modifyData(o){
  var string = JSON.stringify(o);
  string = string.replace(/\"title\":/g, "\"text\":");
  string = string.replace(/\"url\":/g, "\"type\": \"url\", \"url\":");

  var obj = JSON.parse(string);
  console.log('new obj is ', obj);

  return obj;
}

function parseBookmarks(data){
  console.log('the bookmarks are ' , data);

  data = modifyData(data[0].children);

  $('#bookmarks').jstree({
      'core' : {
        //expand_selected_onload : true,
        'data' : data,
        'check_callback' : function(o, n, p, i, m) { //operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more
          //console.log(o,n,p,i,m);
          if(m && m.dnd && m.pos !== 'i') { return false; }
          if(o === "move_node" || o === "copy_node") {
            if(this.get_node(n).parent === this.get_node(p).id) { return false; } //if current nodes parent matches parent nodes id, dont do anything
          }
          return true;
        },
        'themes' : {
          'responsive' : false,
          'variant' : 'small',
          'stripes' : true
        }
      },
      "search": {
            "case_insensitive": true,
            "show_only_matches" : true
      },
      //loaded : runTourStep,
      'sort' : function(a, b) {
        return this.get_type(a) === this.get_type(b) ? (this.get_text(a) > this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1) : (this.get_type(a) >= this.get_type(b) ? 1 : -1);
      },
      'contextmenu' : {
        'items' : bookmarksContextMenu,
        'select_node' : false
      },
      'types' : {
        'default' : { 'icon' : 'images/folder-horizontal.png' },
        'url' : { 'valid_children' : [], 'icon' : 'images/globe_icon.gif' }
      },
      'unique' : {
        'duplicate' : function (name, counter) {
          return name + ' ' + counter;
        }
      },
      'plugins' : ['dnd','types','contextmenu','unique', 'search', 'wholerow'] //took out 'state' plugin
    })

  bookmarkMethods();
}
```

initBookmarks on DOM ready...

So I've tried the following but it does not work!

```
function modifyData(o){
  //that's all... no magic, no bloated framework
  /*traverse(o,function(key,value){

  });*/
  o = o[0].children;
  var string = JSON.stringify(o);
  string = string.replace(/\"title\":/g, "\"text\":");
  string = string.replace(/\"url\":/g, "\"type\": \"url\", \"url\":");

  var obj = JSON.parse(string);
  console.log('new obj is ', obj);

  return obj;
}

function parseBookmarks(){
  //console.log('the bookmarks are ' , data);

  //data = modifyData(data[0].children);

  $('#bookmarks').jstree({
      'core' : {
        //expand_selected_onload : true,
        'data' : chrome.bookmarks.getTree(modifyData),
        'check_callback' : function(o, n, p, i, m) { //operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more
          //console.log(o,n,p,i,m);
          //if(m && m.dnd && m.pos !== 'i') { return false; }
          if(o === "move_node" || o === "copy_node") {
            //if(this.get_node(n).parent === this.get_node(p).id) { return false; } //if current nodes parent matches parent nodes id, dont do anything
          }
          return true;
        },
        'themes' : {
          'responsive' : false,
          'variant' : 'small',
          'stripes' : true
        }
      },
      "search": {
            "case_insensitive": true,
            "show_only_matches" : true
      },
      //loaded : runTourStep,
      'sort' : function(a, b) {
        return this.get_type(a) === this.get_type(b) ? (this.get_text(a) > this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1) : (this.get_type(a) >= this.get_type(b) ? 1 : -1);
      },
      'contextmenu' : {
        'items' : bookmarksContextMenu,
        'select_node' : false
      },
      'types' : {
        'default' : { 'icon' : 'images/folder-horizontal.png' },
        'url' : { 'valid_children' : [], 'icon' : 'images/globe_icon.gif' }
      },
      'unique' : {
        'duplicate' : function (name, counter) {
          return name + ' ' + counter;
        }
      },
      'plugins' : ['dnd','types','contextmenu','unique', 'search', 'wholerow'] //took out 'state' plugin
    })

  bookmarkMethods();
}
```

parseBookmarks() on DOM ready..

Comment: There's [a better example of using the callback](https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-the-tree-using-a-callback-function) on github, I think it provides the answer or hint you seek, if the trouble was how to map chrome bookmarks into jstree specifically.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the example @wOxxOm. I made an attempt as you can see above, but it does not work.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to how to implement it.

Comment: Uhm I just tried the data callback on jsfiddle and I don't see why you need it because *in your case* it appears to be effectively the same as passing the `data` parameter. The only need for this callback function is for dynamically fetched data using custom ajax. Anyway the question doesn't explain what's wrong with the current code and what exactly you want to achieve in the end.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm trying to make it so when I refresh the tree using tree.jstree("refresh")  it grabs all the data for the tree again. Right now, I have to destroy and reinit the tree which makes all the nodes close. I guess I'm only assuming they won't close when I refresh the tree.

Comment: I don't think the `data` callback will magically help you retain the tree state. You'll probably have to first extract the state, refresh the tree, reapply the saved state using straightforward enumeration + some kind of setState.

Comment: You're right! I feel dumb that I forgot that the json for the tree holds the state and that refreshing it would come back without the state. I'll come up with something and post my own answer.

Comment: I was actually able to just create the single node dynamically instead of refreshing the instance... so I don't have an answer to this but I don't need one!